# Android JSONParser, httpclient and cookies

Tags: android, cookies, httpclient

Ok, so I know this has been asked a million times before and I've read most of the posts and answers but it's been a long day and my brain is fried and I just cannot get it to work ...

I have an Android app that I am modifying to login using phpbb3 user tables but am stumped because it needs to have cookies enabled for the login to work.

This is the current httpclient code in my app that works with my old non-phpbb3 user table:

```
// defaultHttpClient
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
is = httpEntity.getContent();
```

What do i need to add to get this to accept cookies? must be able to work from API 8 up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DefaultHttpClient handles cookies out of the box you just need to reuse same client instead of creating new one for each request.

Comment: Turns out the problem was between the keyboard and chair .... but Nikita's answer helped me figure that out.